# How jest in Angularjs handle all my module dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Updated: I did not use any module loader, because this is old project, emm, so I just import all dependencies in my `index.html` via `script` tag

---

My AngularJS has a structure like this:

- **app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['LocalStorageModule', 'ngCookies', ...])
```

- **testController**

```
angular.module('app').controller('testController', function(){})
```

now I want to test `testController`, so my jest UT code:

- **testController.spec.js**

```
require('./testController.controller')

describe('TestController', () => {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
})
```

but now I got an error:

`Module 'app' is not available`

that means I must import `app.js`, but if I import `app.js`,  I also got

`Failed to instantiate module LocalStorageModule due to: Module 'LocalStorageModule' is not available!`

So I have to import all my dependencies(twenty an more installed by bower) in my every test file? I think it isn't a good way. How to handle this solution? import all my components installed by bower?

Comment: Do you use any kind of module loader such as webpack?
If so, you app file should import its all deps.

Comment: @felixmosh not yet, I did not use any module loader, just import these modules in my index.html

Comment: So in that case i dint have alot of choices, u need to provide all the angular deps within jest.

Comment: Maybe this post will guide you, https://medium.com/@abdoulayektr/migrating-angularjs-tests-from-karma-to-jest-4719785060b5

Comment: thx~, it seems I have found some solutions from your comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the angular.js dependency injection. Because you have some dependencies declared in your app module. You need to mock your app module and then you need to inject the dependencies.

```
describe('TestController', () => {
  beforeEach(
      angular.mock.module('app')
  );

  let _localStorageModule;
  let _ngCookies;


  beforeEach(
      inject((LocalStorageModule, ngCookies) => {
          _localStorageModule = LocalStorageModule;
          _ngCookies = ngCookies;
      })
  );
})
```

Comment: this way would have an error, because in `testController`, it uses `angular.module('app').controller`, and it would throw `Module app is not available
` when I import `testController`. And In this way, do need to import all deps file?